# Issues posting data on local server

Tags: connection, reset, iis-7

I am running IIS 7 on my Windows 7 computer.

The problem I am facing is if I am on a web page for too long, then go to make a POST request the server doesn't respond.

If I make the POST request as soon as I load the page then its fine,  the problem only occurs when I have been on the page for say 4-5 minutes before submitting the post.

If i use Firefox it will tell me that the connection has been reset.

I wlil be looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Sounds like possibly a session timeout

Comment: I know it isn't a PHP/programming error as I have used the some software on other servers. Could it maybe be a PHP INI configuration?

Comment: Ya if it is session problems and its ASP your using the check this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I'm only a PHP developer.  I will have a search around though.  Other answers are still welcome :)